# Regex for specific input with only numbers and delimiters ("," and ";") are allowed

Tags: java, regex

I would like to validate an input (of type String) which have delimiters (only "," or ";") followed by a number of specific length e.g. input1=444554; 445148, 41412; and input2=414454, 784554, etc.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than that and post your problematic attempt to get any joy.

Comment: By "a number of specific length" do you mean a six-(decimal-)digit number?  Do the two delimiters have different significance that the pattern would need to account for?  Are the "input1=" and "input2=" part of the input you want to validate? Must the inputs be terminated by a delimiter, as your input1 is?  Your examples contain whitespace, which you didn't mention in your description.  What are the rules for that?  There may be other ambiguities, too.

Comment: @JohnBollinger lets say 6 digit number allowed string should be String test = input1 or String test = input2 did you get my point now ? Yes the inputs should always be terminated by a delimiter (and only allowed delimiters are "," or ";")

Comment: No, I don't yet fully get your point.  In the first place, please clarify the requirements by [editing the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56775456/edit).  In the second place, since the "input1=" bits are part of the input to be validated, please clarify the requirements for that part.  Third, you did not address the question of whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that this expression might likely validate that:

```
^(.*?)=\K(\s*([0-9]{6})\s*[;,])+\s*$
```

and we can add more boundaries, if we wish to, for instance we can change `(.*?)` with input names, if necessary.

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/g6mZsF/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^(.*?)=\\K(\\s*([0-9]{6})\\s*[;,])+\\s*$";
final String string = "input1=444554; 445148, 414121;\n"
     + "input1=444554; 445148, 41412;\n"
     + "input2=414454, \n"
     + "input1=444554; 44514, 414121;\n"
     + "input1=444554; 445141, 414121; 414121\n"
     + "input2:414454, ";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

I have assumed that

```
input1=444554; 445141, 414121; 414121
```

is undesired since it is not followed by `,` or `;`.

---

#### Edit:

### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vxZMr2/1/)

Comment: the string should only be final String string = "444554; 445148, 414121;" like that, could you please edit your answer

Comment: yes it is correct.